# AWS cloudwatch runtime capture

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

How can we capture all the runtimes above 700ms in AWS cloud watch?
Triggering the AWS lambda function, using a python script.

Comment: Please add more details about the process and share with us what have you tried so far in order to help you better.

Comment: AWS records all lambda execution times in CloudWatch by default (Duration metric under Lambda) Depending what are you trying to do, it is easy to create an alarm if the threshold is above, etc.